# No subject alternative names matching IP address xxx.xx.x found - LDAPS

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, jboss, ldap

While connecting to LDAPS IP we are getting below error .

```
{
    "error":"unauthorized",
    "error_description":"simple bind failed: xxx.xx.x nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: xxx.xx.x **[Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address xxx.xx.x found]**"
}
```

We have installed certificate in both JDK(1.8) & JRE(1.8), added LDAPS IP in Property file(Spring boot) and deployed in JBOSS WildFly 11 Server.
We have tried below steps by looking at various links to resolve the above error but no solution as of now

```
- Installing certificate either in JDK or JRE and in both
- Adding `-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true` in WildFly conf.bat (`set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%`)
- Adding -Djdk.tls.trustNameService=true in WildFly conf.bat (`set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%`)
```

Can anyone help to solve this issue. Let me know if any further information required.

Comment: You appear to be using an LDAPS URL containing an IP address instead of a hostname. Use the hostname.

Comment: @user207421 . Thanks for your reply . I have tried with the host name . But got "No Subject alternative DNS name matching hostname found"

Comment: After downgrading java version to 1.8.0_152 it works . But version above that throws the error "No Subject alternative DNS name matching hostname found".